# How can I enclose these build steps?

Tags: msbuild

I've been working on tacking on a deployment operations to my web project file so that I can deploy a web project from TeamCity. How can I enclose the  and  steps so that I do not need to repeat the condition check?

```
<Target Name="Deploy">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Development-Publish' ">
    <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\development.txt</ScriptPath>
    <DeploymentPath>\\devserver\dev</DeploymentPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Integration-Publish' ">
    <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\integration.txt</ScriptPath>
    <DeploymentPath>\\integrationserver\int</DeploymentPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Staging-Publish' ">
    <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\staging.txt</ScriptPath>
    <DeploymentPath>\\stagingserver\staging</DeploymentPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BeyondCompareCommand>C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe</BeyondCompareCommand>
    <AdditionalArguments>/silent /closescript</AdditionalArguments>
    <DeploymentCommand>"$(BeyondCompareCommand)" @"$(ScriptPath)" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)" "$(DeploymentPath)" $(AdditionalArguments)</DeploymentCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Condition=" '$(DeploymentPath)' != '' " Importance="high" Text="Executing Deployment with this command: $(DeploymentCommand)" />
  <Exec Condition=" '$(DeploymentPath)' != '' " Command="$(DeploymentCommand)" />
</Target>
```

I thought that I should have a `<Target Name="DeploymentParameters"/>` which `<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="DeploymentParameters"/>` but unless I made a mistake, it appeared I couldn't access the properties declared in the `DeploymentParameters` target.

Comment: I think you need to use the output element in your DeploymentParameters task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164287.aspx

Comment: @Jim it appears the Output element is a child element of a task like `Exec` or `Csc`

Comment: Yeah, I just looked a little closer.  In my scripts, instead of conditional properties, i have conditional Exec commands, but that's what you're apparently trying to avoid.

Comment: @Jim for this given example I could probably just use a message task, but it seems like the result would be more work than the repetition. I guess maybe I could define the PropertyGroups globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Development-Publish' ">
  <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\development.txt</ScriptPath>
  <DeploymentPath>\\devserver\dev</DeploymentPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Integration-Publish' ">
  <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\integration.txt</ScriptPath>
  <DeploymentPath>\\integrationserver\int</DeploymentPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Staging-Publish' ">
  <ScriptPath>c:\scripts\staging.txt</ScriptPath>
  <DeploymentPath>\\stagingserver\staging</DeploymentPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <BeyondCompareCommand>C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe</BeyondCompareCommand>
  <AdditionalArguments>/silent /closescript</AdditionalArguments>
  <DeploymentCommand>"$(BeyondCompareCommand)" @"$(ScriptPath)" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)" "$(DeploymentPath)" $(AdditionalArguments)</DeploymentCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="Deploy" Condition=" '$(DeploymentPath)' != '' " >
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Executing Deployment with this command: $(DeploymentCommand)" />
  <Exec Command="$(DeploymentCommand)" />
</Target>
```